# How to SQL ORDER BY but keep the results clumped according to another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with two columns `name` and `age`.  I want to keep the names clumped together but order the clumps by the clump containing the youngest age.

```
Merlot   12
Cab       8
Merlot    6 
Cab      10
```

I want to perform a query resulting in...

```
Merlot   12
Merlot    6
Cab       8
Cab      10
```

How would you perform this SQL query?

Comment: Can you show your result that you want to see and the query you have now?

Comment: Overly simplistic sample data can easily mislead you. Explain why Merlot precedes Cab. What happens if Beaujolais appears? And are values like "12" really the age of the wine (bottle)? Next year, do you expect everything to be incremented by 1? Typically one stores a date (or vintage year for wine) and not a specific point-in-time value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
order by min(age) over (partition by name),
         name
```

It is very important to use `name` as the second key.  This handles the case where two names have the same minimum -- the rows for the names are guaranteed to be separated.

Answer (score 0):

I *assume* there is some kind of ID column, as `Merlot` is sorted in age descending, and `Cab` ascending; so something you haven't shown us is determining that order. Anyway, you can do this with a window function:

```sql
ORDER BY MIN(Age) OVER (PARTITION BY [name]) ASC, 
         YourID ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this expression to the `order by`... either in a subquery or the outer query... you don't have to ultimately select it.

```sql
row_number() over (partition by name order by age)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to order by age as well. Add this to the end of your query might do the trick

```
ORDER BY name, age
```